# Chained Comboboxes Extjs getfilter error

Tags: javascript, extjs

View:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    anchor: '100%',
    reference: 'il',
    fieldLabel: 'İl',
    name: 'il',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    displayField: 'il',
    store: 'il',
    cls :'text-font',
    baseCls :'fieldcolor',
    valueField: 'il'
},
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    anchor: '100%',
    reference: 'ilce',
    fieldLabel: 'İlce',
    name: 'ilce',
    forceSelection: true,
    typeAhead: true,
    displayField: 'ilce',
    store: 'ilce',
    filters: {
        property: 'il',
        value: 'ilid'
    },
    cls :'text-font',
    baseCls :'fieldcolor',
    valueField: 'ilce'
},
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('ertg.model.ilmodel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'il'
        },
        {
            name: 'ilid'
        }
    ]
});
```

Another model:

```
Ext.define('ertg.model.ilcemodel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {
            name: 'ilce'
        },
        {
            name: 'ilid'
        }
    ]
});
```

Hi guys,This my comboboxes is run error .error this:Uncaught TypeError: me.store.getFilters is not a function
    at constructor.onEndUpdateFilters

Whats Problem ??

Thanks

Ertugrul

Comment: Please share the code of your stores `il` and `ilce`. Check that both stores extend `Ext.data.Store`.

Comment: share the stores and i'm controling the code now is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xtype `combobox` simply has no `filters {}` config. in order to filter the entries of a `combobox`, one has to configure an event listener, which then calls `store.filter()`, while passing on the property & value to filter for... just see the API docs: it's [config filters](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-filters) vs. [method filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.data.Store.html#method-filter) ...while both of them belong to the `store` - and not the `combobox`. the docs for [Ext.util.Filter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.util.Filter.html) are also relevant.

based upon the provided code below, I'd suggest to write it alike this (the `requires` should already be loaded by the `store` class, would omit them, too... only know that I never require any them):

```
Ext.define('ertg.store.ilce', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['ertg.model.ilcemodel'],
    model: 'ertg.model.ilcemodel',
    storeId: 'ilce',
    filters: null,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/data/ilce.json',
        reader: {type: 'json'},
        writer: {type: 'json'}
    }
});
```